# Definition of operator->() in c++

Tags: c++, list, operators, operator-overloading, std

Please tell me how the operator->() in being defined for the iterator of std::list in order to refer members of the element that is being pointed by an iterator.

EDIT:

The problem is that if you implement like this (Fred Nurk):

```
template<class T>
struct list {
private:
  struct Node {  // internal class that actually makes up the list structure
    Node *prev, *next;
    T data;
  };

public:
  struct iterator {  // iterator interface to the above internal node type
    T* operator->() const {
      return &_node->data;
    }
  private:
    Node *_node;
  }
};
```

Then when you write:

```
struct A {
  int n;
};
void f() {
  list<A> L;  // imagine this is filled with some data
  list<A>::iterator x = L.begin();

  x->n = 42;
}
```

Then

x->n I understand like x->operator->()n which is equivalent to (A ponter to a)n which is a nonsence. How to understand this part. Some answers tell that it is equivalent to x->operator->()->n; (instead of x->operator->()n) but I don't understand why. **Please explain me this.**

Comment: There's no operator-> in std::list.

Comment: That is true. I have missed the "iterator".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With many details elided, here is the gist of how it works:

```
template<class T>
struct list {
private:
  struct Node {  // internal class that actually makes up the list structure
    Node *prev, *next;
    T data;
  };

public:
  struct iterator {  // iterator interface to the above internal node type
    T* operator->() const {
      return &_node->data;
    }
  private:
    Node *_node;
  }
};
```

Thus, given:

```
struct A {
  int n;
};
void f() {
  list<A> L;  // imagine this is filled with some data
  list<A>::iterator x = L.begin();

  x->n = 42;
  // x.operator->() returns an A*
  // which gets -> applied again with "n"
}
```

Comment: But we have no two operators->. Why it is applied twice?

Comment: @Narek: Though I believe your reliance on standardese is unhelpful at your apparent level, even though you keep asking for it, see §13.5.6 in C++03.

Comment: Thank you very much (and +1) for warm words ;) and also for the answer. Yes I see that answer in §13.5.6, that is, "An expression x->m is interpreted as (x.operator->())->m ........"

Answer (score 3):

(hint: It returns a pointer to the element.)

Comment: I think you nailed it perfectly :)

Comment: I know but the problem is that how when I write my_iterator->member_name, then I obtain the "member_name" member of the element that is pointed by the my_iterator?

Comment: @Narek: another hint: it's an unary operator.

Comment: Thanks guys. And one more hint on my behalf: it is the operator->() ;)

Answer (score 3):

The `->` operator behaves as follows:

```
T->x; // some field
T->foo(); // some function
```

...is equivalent to:

```
T.operator->()->x;
T.operator->()->foo();
```

Note the re-application of `->` to whatever is returned.

Comment: Is the re-application defined by the standard?

Comment: Yes. Check out section 5.2.5.

Comment: I can not see there any sentence that pointes to double invocation of operator->(). Please cite the paragraph.

Comment: @Narek: Sorry, that was the wrong section. It looks like Fred has already provided the correct one, though.

Answer (score 2):

Operator `->` is implemented differently than the other operators in C++. The operator function is expected to return a pointer, and the `->` is applied again to that pointer.

Comment: @Narek - it's being accomplished by design.

Comment: @Narek, it's C++ compiler magic as defined by Bjarne Stroustrup and the C++ standardization committee.

Answer (score 1):

It returns pointer. Just for completeness, here is simple example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class SafeVectorIterator
{
    vector<T> & _vec;
    size_t _pos;
public:
    SafeVectorIterator(vector<T> & vec) : _vec(vec), _pos(0) { }

    void operator++() { ++_pos; }
    void operator--() { --_pos; }

    T& operator*() { return _vec.at(_pos); }
    T* operator->() { return &_vec.at(_pos); }

};

struct point { int x, y; }; 

int main()
{
    vector<point> vec;
    point p = { 1, 2 };
    vec.push_back(p);
    vec.push_back(p);
    SafeVectorIterator<point> it(vec);
    ++it;
    it->x = 8;
    cout << (*it).y << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's a curious op-- you have there.